# JQuery parent() selector on submit button selects container not form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

On my page, there are two forms. I'd like to select only the one for which the submit button is clicked.

I would think the following should do the trick:

```
$("#signup,#login").submit(function(){
    $(this).parent("form:first").css('background-color', 'red');
    return false;   
});
```

But with the "form:first" selector, nothing happens (likely because it is selecting the container div). Without the "form:first" selector, the container div is selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/tenfold/gupGD/

Can anyone help with what's going on here? Many thanks.

Comment: `$(this).parent().find('form:first')` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do

```
$(this).css('background-color', 'red');
```

The submission event is bound to the form itself.

Also, you shouldn't use `return false`, but use the event as a parameter and call `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: "but use the event as a parameter and call event.preventDefault()" - generally that's true, but in this case stopping the event bubbling won't harm anything; submit events are only meaningful for forms.

Comment: @SamDufel indeed, but I'd rather teach the *correct* way to do this

Comment: +1 exactly @ExplosionPills, You always give great and precise answers. Was just trying to make the same point [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14712593/1880925)

Comment: @ROYFinley you'll find it *very* hard to win an argument against any developer who knows what he's doing even if he's wrong.

Comment: @ExplosionPills  Probably, right LOL... as my profile on here says, been doing it 18 years and learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.closest()` method

```
$("#signup,#login").submit(function(){
    $(this).closest("form").css('background-color', 'red');
    return false;   
});
```

Comment: I never knew that `closest` could select the element itself.  That's an extra step, though.

Comment: @Explosion Pills You're absolutely right, in this particular example it's an extra step. The ability to test the element itself by .closest method is more useful when using mouse event types. I think your answer is more correct than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `parents()` instead of `parent()`.

Extract from doc [here](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) :

> The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the
>   latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree.

Comment: Very nice comment but put it in comment section plz.