# success callback in a click event on ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following method:

```
$('.size-list .size').live('click',function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'/item/colors/'+ currentItem.id +"/"+$(this).attr('data-name'),
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(attributes){
                     //have some callback here to the click function    
                },
                error: function(res){

                },
            });
        }
    });
```

and here's how I am calling it:

```
$(".size-list li[data-name='" + size + "']").trigger('click');
```

How can I modify the function above such that when the ajax calls succeed I can execute a function in the `.trigger('click')`. Basically I wanted to do something upon the ajax success call after I click on it.

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712337/callback-after-jquery-trigger-function

Comment: can you a bit more clear on your question? Actually i couldn't get what you suppose to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Edited by the comment.

```
$('.size-list .size').live('click',function(){
            var that = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url:'/item/colors/'+ currentItem.id +"/"+$(this).attr('data-name'),
                type: 'GET',
                success: doSomething; //<-- Something like this???    
                },
                error: function(res){

                },
            });
        }
    });

function doSomething(response) {
  // do something here;
}
```

Comment: no..I want it to be a generic function.. I want to have a callback in the ajax success

Comment: @adit I've changed the answer, is that what you want?

Comment: no.. I don't want it to be like that.. I want a callback when I trigger the click that the ajax is successful

Comment: Sorry. My english is not so good, I can't understand what do you want

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to call a function in the success call?

```
$('.size-list .size').live('click',function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'/item/colors/'+ currentItem.id +"/"+$(this).attr('data-name'),
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(attributes){
                     that.doSomething();    
                },
                error: function(res){

                },
            });
        }
    });
```

And execute a function in the trigger click?

```
that.doSomething = function() {
        $(".size-list li[data-name='" + size + "']").click(function() {             
        });
    }
};
```